# Storing files in folder structure and maintaining its state in mysql database

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot

I have a requirement where I have to store files in the server along with the folder structure. And in the UI part, if the user clicks on a specific folder, only the sub-folders and files belonging to that folder should be shown to the user on the screen.

How to design database in these kind of situation? The number of sub-folders, a parent folder can contain is not fixed, it can have 0-n sub-folders.

Answer (score 3):

With MySQl, you can simply achieve this Here is a good link: http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/